# compare text of two textfield by using relation operator

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

i am a new beginner of iphone developer and i want to compare my  two text feild value so please tell me how can i do this with useing realtion operator..
i have use this code

```
if([uname.text] != [password.text]){
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"u dont enter uname and password" message:@"pls enter" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Wanna enter" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

and get this error

error: expected ':' before ']' token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(![uname.text isEqualtoString: password.text]){
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"u dont enter uname and password" message:@"pls enter" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Wanna enter" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: The atrocious text speak in your message prevents me from upvoting this.

Answer (score 3):

Relational operators wont work for `NSString`.. Use `isEqualToString` method

```
if(![uname.text isEqualToString:password.text])
```

And regarding your error remove those [ ].

Answer (score 3):

```
if (![uname.text isEqualtoString: password.text]) {
    //do something
}
```

it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Confusion for me :
**Are you checking for username/paswword is empty, or you are checking that both username and password has the same value**

> **As your alert message is different from the condition you are applying**

```
NSString* userName = uname.text;
NSString* pwd = password.text;

if(([userName length] < 0) && ([pwd length] < 0)){

      UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"u dont enter uname and password" message:@"pls enter" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Wanna enter" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your writting `[uname.text] != [password.text]` this is syntactically wrong.use `uname.text != password.text`   .

my suggestion is you have to compare two strings by isEqualToString:

ex:

```
if(![string1 isEqualToString:string2]){

///bla bla

}
```

1`.[string1 isEqualToString:string2]` compares two strings values

2.`string1 == string2` compares two string object reference